# How to make Python execute a command when a key is detected to be pressed

Tags: python, keyboard

I want to make Python execute my command when a key is pressed.
Like if "a" is pressed, the output should be:

```
A is pressed
```

or like it asks you to press key "a" and if you press it, its output should be `Thanks for pressing the key! We are processing!`

Sorry if I'm not clear, I'm actually not english

Comment: Are you asking how to take input from the user? How to do react to different inputs differently? Or maybe to make Python not wait for enter to be pressed?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'm asking how to execute a command when a key is pressed.

Comment: @Martineau I'm using Windows 10

Comment: @JamesRogers you've already said that. However, this is not enough detail. This problem can be understood in different ways, and I had three guesses in the comment above.

Comment: Since you're using Windows, you can use the kbhit() and `getch()` in the WIndows-only `msvcrt` module.

Comment: @NieDzejkob My answer : "How to do react to different inputs differently?"

Comment: @JamesRogers With an `if` statement.

Comment: @blhsing Ah, I meant, the program should immediately execute a command when a SPECIFIED KEY is pressed. And I'm sure it cannot be done with an IF Statement. So next time, understand my question first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't need this to work when the window is not in focus, you should use `getch` from `msvcrt` to react to the keypresses immediately and then `if` and `elif` to distinguish the keys. I'd also recommend normalizing the case of the keys with `upper` or `lower`:

```
import msvcrt

while True:
    key = msvcrt.getch().lower()

    if key == b'a':
        print("You've pressed A. I'll now do the thing I'm supposed to do when you press A.")
    elif key == b'q':
        print("Quitting...")
        break
    else:
        print("You've pressed a key I don't know how to handle! PANIC!")
```

Comment: That wasn't what I was looking for but its good. Nice. And btw, I was actually looking for something that actually doesn't exist in Python, lol, but this is the best answer. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can call `msvcrt.getch()` to get the character of a single key press.

```
>>> import msvcrt
>>> msvcrt.getch()
b'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

If using *Windows OS*, you can use *msvcrt* module as explained in other answers.

Or, you can simply get user input and check if it is corresponding key.

```
key = input('press key') 

if key == 'a':
    print('a is pressed')
```

But, user must press enter after the key.

Third option would be to use GUI library like *Tkinter*. Check [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) short tutorial for **Events and Bindings** in *Tkinter*.

Answer (score 0):

You need some module that can handle key or mouse events. Depending what you want to achieve you can use for example Tkinter or even Pygame